# Related rates problem (right-triangle kind): two ships going south and west

Tags: calculus

I am asked to solve the following problem:

> At 8am ship A is 25 km south of ship B. If the ship A is travelling west at the speed of 16 km/h and ship B is going south at 20 km/h, find the rate of change of the distance between them at 8:30am.

From my calculations I got

$$y = 15 km \quad x = 8 \ km \quad$$

\begin{align*}
2d d' &= 2x x' + 2y y' \\
17d' &= 8 \cdot 16 - 15 \cdot 20\\
d' &= 10.12 \ km/h
\end{align*}

I would appreciate is someone could check this result, since the textbook's answer is $V' = 3 \ m^3/h$ which does not make sense, definitely a mistyped answer =)

Comment: Well, the units are certainly wrong. Looks like an answer to a different question, one about the rate of change of a volume.

Comment: Check the sign of your answer. Just from the description of the situation, the ships probably aren’t getting farther apart after a half hour.

Answer (score 0):

Your work is correct except for a sign error in the final step.  Notice that 
$$17d' = 8 \cdot 16 - 15 \cdot 20 = 128 - 300 = -172$$  Hence, $d' = -10.12~\text{km}/\text{h}$, as the calculation below shows.

Consider the diagram below:

[image: distance_between_ships]

The distance ship A travels west is $16t~\text{km}$, where $t$ is the time in hours after 8:00 am.  The distance ship B travels south is $20t~\text{km}$, where $t$ is the time in hours after 8:00 am.  Since ship B is initially $25~\text{km}$ north of ship A, the north-south distance between them at time $t$ is $(25 - 20t)~\text{km}$.  The east-west distance between them at time $t$ is $16t~\text{km}$.  By the Pythagorean Theorem, the square of the distance between them is 
$$d^2 = \left(25~\text{km} - 20~\frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}} \cdot t\right)^2 + \left(16~\frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}} \cdot t\right)^2$$
Differentiating with respect to time yields
\begin{align*}
2dd' & = 2\left(25~\text{km} - 20~\frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}} \cdot t\right)\left(-20~\frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}}\right) + 2\left(16~\frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}} \cdot t\right)\left(16~\frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}}\right)\\
dd' & = \left(25~\text{km} - 20~\frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}} \cdot t\right)\left(-20~\frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}}\right) + \left(16~\frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}} \cdot t\right)\left(16~\frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}}\right)\\
dd' & = -500~\frac{\text{km}^2}{\text{h}} + 400t~\frac{\text{km}^2}{\text{h}^2} + 256t~\frac{\text{km}^2}{\text{h}^2}\\
dd' & = -500~\frac{\text{km}^2}{\text{h}} + 656t~\frac{\text{km}^2}{\text{h}^2}\\
d' & = \dfrac{-500~\frac{\text{km}^2}{\text{h}} + 656t~\frac{\text{km}^2}{\text{h}^2}}{d}\\
\end{align*}
As you worked out, at 8:30 am, ship A has traveled $8~\text{km}$ west of its initial location and ship B has traveled $10~\text{km}$ south of its initial location, leaving it $15~\text{km}$ north of ship A's initial location.  Consequently, the ships are $17~\text{km}$ apart at 8:30 am.  Substituting $17~\text{km}$ for $d$ and $1/2~\text{h}$ for $t$ yields
\begin{align*}
d' & = \dfrac{-500~\frac{\text{km}^2}{\text{h}} + 656~\frac{\text{km}^2}{\text{h}^2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}~\text{h}}{17~\text{km}}\\
d' & = \dfrac{-500~\frac{\text{km}^2}{\text{h}} + 328~\frac{\text{km}^2}{\text{h}}}{17~\text{km}}\\
d' & = \dfrac{-172~\frac{\text{km}^2}{\text{h}}}{17~\text{km}}\\
d' & = -10.12~\frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}}
\end{align*}